# How to find a deleted SSRS subscription that still runs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs, sql-server-agent, ssrs-2016

In troubleshooting an 'SSRS won't email subscriptions' problem I created a test subscription. I then found the SQL Agent job and changed the owner (I read the disclaimer in the job description, ignored it, and now I'm here) after which the subscription successfully ran and emailed the report as desired, confirming to my satisfaction that the problem I was troubleshooting related to the credentials SSRS used when creating the subscription.

I then deleted my test subscription from inside the SSRS myreportserver/Reports/manage/subscriptions page, and the subscription disappeared from the subscriptions page and the associated job disappeared from the SQL Agent job list as expected. However, the subscription/job still emails out a static copy of the report that matches the first emailed copy.

Things I've tried:

1. I've looked in `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` with the following query to see if I could find the job by execution date, however the email sent by the subscription states that it was executed at 10:33:01 AM (which can vary by a couple of seconds day to day, interesting as the report being sent is now a static copy), and nothing shows as executed between 10:01:00 and 10:48:00. This isn't surprising since the job no longer shows in the SQL Agent list and the report being emailed is static.

```
SELECT s.name
    , s.description
    , sa.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs s
    RIGHT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sa ON s.job_id = sa.job_id
ORDER BY sa.start_execution_date DESC
```

2. I've looked in the SSRS log file, there is no information about the subscription showing there, which is not surprising as the subscription has been deleted.
3. I’ve looked in the ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3 view, it does not show the report being executed anywhere near that time, not surprising as the copy of the report being emailed is static.
4. I've restarted the SSRS and SQL Agent services, I really had hopes on the SSRS service restart fixing it, but no.

Where can I look to find this deleted subscription that is running every morning at 10:33~ AM, and then once found how can I delete it for good?